# error in Prolog code - undefined procedure: unique/1

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

%three variants of actions. I have 3 animals and it can drive on plane, car or miss the %step. I know, that on the first step monkey ride on plane, wolf ride on car. On the second %step wolf ride on plane. We need to know accordance that remain. And each animal ride on %each vehicle only on time

```
action(plane).
action(car).
action(shift).
```

%I declare passenger iside my function solve

```
solve([passenger(monkey, [X1,X2,X3]), passenger(wolf, [Y1, Y2,Y3]),
passenger(hippo, [Z1, Z2, Z3])]):-
   action(X1), action(Y1), action(Z1), unique([X1, Y1, Z1]),
   action(X2), action(Y2), action(Z2), unique([X2, Y2, Z2]),
   action(X3), action(Y3), action(Z3), unique([X3, Y3, Z3]),

   unique([X1, X2, X3]), unique([Y1, Y2, Y3]), unique([Z1, Z2, Z3]),

   X1 = plane, Y1 = car,
   Y2 = plane.
```

Comment: *Undefined procedure unique/1* means you haven't defined the `unique` predicate anywhere with one argument.

Answer (score 2):

Probably `unique/1` is all different:

```
unique([]).
unique([E|Es]) :-
   maplist(dif(E), Es),
   unique(Es).
```

Comment: And what I have to do?

Comment: @Zakhar: Include above into your program. Ideally before the `action/1` facts